# Reversing decryption function involving XORs and bit rotations?

Tags: encryption, xor

I am trying to reverse this equation to find the encrypted number given to it. Here is the equation:

$$y = x \oplus n \oplus (x \ggg 3) \oplus (x \lll 7) $$

$\oplus$ is the bitwise exclusive or function
$a \lll b$ is $a$ bit rotated left by $b$ bits
$a \ggg b$ is $a$ bit rotated right by $b$ bits

$y$ is a known 32 bit integer
$n$ is a known 32 bit integer but unique for every $x$ and $y$
$x$ is the encrypted message and what I want to solve for, and it is an unknown 32 bit integer

Comment: You can trivially eliminate $n$. After that you have 32 linear equations modulo 2 and 32 unknowns. Apply standard techniques for solving a system of linear equations, or if you're lazy brute-force it (should only take a couple of seconds).

Comment: Related: [How to break an arbitrary XOR and Rotation based encryption?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6045/how-to-break-an-arbitrary-xor-and-rotation-based-encryption)

Comment: "$n$ is a known 32 bit integer but unique for every $x$ and $y$"; is $n$ a function of $x$, $y$, or both? If the latter, the system is under determined afaict.

Comment: I took it to mean `n` is a nonce.

Comment: Ok, then my answer should be alright. Give me a ping (or file an edit) if I misdid my indices...

Answer (score 6):

I'll demonstrate a "brute" way of doing it; should work for any XOR-rot system. Please note that indices are $\bmod 32$.

You basically write your equation in 32-vector and matrix notation:

$$
\bar{y} = M\bar{x} \oplus \bar{n},
$$ or in [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) (which, in my opinion, can make stuff more readable)
$$
y_i=M_{ij}x^j \oplus n_i,
$$ where the sum goes from $i=1\dots32$.

Now, the magic part (to solve the rotation) lies in finding the $32\times32$ matrix $M_{ij}$:

$$
M_{ij}=\delta_{ij}\oplus\delta_{(i+3),j}\oplus\delta_{(i-7),j},
$$ where $\delta_{ij}$ is the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) symbol (the unit matrix):

$$
\delta_{ij} =
    \begin{cases}
            1, &         \text{if } i=j,\\
            0, &         \text{if } i\neq j.
    \end{cases}
$$
Now your problem is reduced to inverting $M_{ij}$ (which is a one-time static thing), and calculating

$$
\bar{x}=M^{-1}(\bar{y}+\bar{n})
$$

Comment: I added a link about the Einstein summation convention as well as an inline definition of the Kronecker delta. Hope you don't mind! Also, `\bmod` is better with the spacing when you type `\mod 32`.